# How do I remove this cabinet at the top of my fridge cavity?

Tags: drywall, refrigerator, cabinets

There were 4 horizontal screws, which I have removed, but the cabinet is still firmly in place. I suspect it is glued in. I think there are two parts. The side panels, which are attached to the dry wall; and the internal cabinet.

What do you think of this course of action?

1. Use a hand saw to saw in between the internal cabinet and the side panels.
2. After this, hopefully can just unscrew the side panels and they aren't also glued to the drywall?

This would probably damage the cabinet, but we would be more concerned with the drywall.

[n.b The cabinent does not go all the way back. There is a space between it and the back wall.]

[image]

Edit:
Some more photos I now managed to get under 2MB:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit 2: Photo of screws

[image]

Comment: where did you find the 4 screws ? are there any in the top panel ?, covered with paint or plugs ? Presumably no glue used.

Comment: 2 on the left, 2 on the right side. There were no other screws, covered by plugs or paint.

Comment: There is an extra panel on the right side. It may have been screwed to the wall, then the slightly narrower cabinet glued and screwed to it. Why? Because evil cabinet installer.

Comment: The extra panels are on both the left and the right. I hope they are just screwed to the wall, and that their purpose was so that the narrower cabinet can be glued in without placing glue on the wall.

Comment: Try using a strong magnet to look for additional screws hidden under the surface.

Comment: Also, see if you can remove the vertical strips along the extreme left and right "side panels", next to the drywall. There doesn't seem to be any reason for them (assuming that the cabinets were always painted) and they may conceal more screws. I doubt there's glue involved, but you may have to demolish it to get it out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

knock the back panel out, saw the bottom panel in half, fold the side panels inwards.

If you want to keep it intact then as they say "removal is the inverse of fittment", you'll have to figure out how it was fitted.

Comment: I will try to unscrew the back panel first. What do you mean by folding the side panels inwards? What I suspect with the initial fitting is that the side panels were attached to the drywall/plaster board first, whether by screws alone or glue+screws, and then the inner cabinet was fixed in with glue+screws.

Comment: Folding them inwards: after you've removed the bottom panel, you can try pulling the side panels on the bottom end, causing them to 'fold' towards the top of the cabinet (and hopefully releasing them). Considering there is an extra panel on the right, perhaps removing that one will reveal extra screws. If panel wide glue was involved (usually a rectangle of glue near the edges, and multiple S-shapes or a big glue cross in the middle) this might be difficult though.

Comment: I think this is the best place to start. Once you do you'll see if glue was used on the cabinet. People that like to glue and screw do it on everything. If so you'll probably have a hard time getting those side panels apart.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the countless photos. Now I see framing on the sides of the cabinet, since the cabinet is smaller than the opening.

[image: frame]

[image: under the cabinet]

Also the screw holes are suspiciously close to the front and not in the middle of the cabinet. So the question is was the cabinet screwed to the frame. How long where the screws (less than 2 inch ?

Mystery solved.
The cabinet was screwed to the board, and the board is still screwed to the wall.

[image: screw]

No glue used, so give the cabinet a hard huge downward (or hit it with rubber hammer), to loosen it.

Comment: Do you mean with the side of the wall? That is some paint that got onto the cabinet. There isn't any caulk around it. Though I will try to use a putty knife to get between the side panel and the inner cabinet,

Comment: @Platypus sorry, it looked like caulk, especial on the top

Comment: Looks like a regular recess on top, probably a wooden plank with a white finishing on the side. Considering the cabinet is firmly in place, I suspect there's more than just a small line of glue at the front.

Comment: @Platypus  also screw the screws back in half a way, then knock on them with a hammer, gently, I do not know what anchors type was used, but it might be holding the cabinet Sticking out. If you feel courageous, use a drill larger then hole and drill, but watch your depth.

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes. But, wouldn't knocking on the screws push the anchors further into the wall? Shouldn't I screw the screws half way in, to secure the screw to the anchor, and then try to pull them out with pliers or something?

Comment: @Platypus You can try to full the anchors out or just knock them in.  Finally just use a drill and drill in to remove the anchor if it is stuck in the hole.

Comment: @Platypus There are two possible ways to install the cabinet. Pre drill in exact location in the wall and insert an anchor flush with the wall. Now match the holes in the cabinet to the anchos in the wall. All this could be tricky to do. The other method, drill a hole in cabinet then insert the screw with anchor on it and push it in. In this case the hole is bigger than the screw to allow anchor to go true. In this case the anchor might be still partially in the hole and not flush with the wall.

Comment: @Platypus  How long where the screws ? like 2 inch or longer ?

Comment: @Ruskes I've uploaded a photo of the screws. It doesn't look like the screws were meant to attach the inner cabinet to the wall frame,  just to the side panels. They are just under 2 inches.

Comment: @Platypus and now we know. There is a side board, that is screwed to the wall, and the cabinet wes screwed to that side board.